# Does alternative reality theoretically prove?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations

Does Hugh Evert theory means Alternative-Reality (or in general, Parallel-Worlds) and [Many-Worlds-Interpretation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-worlds_interpretation) theoretically prove?
Or are scientists have any progress to prove it?

Comment: Many-worlds theory has not been proven, it still remains speculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, such things are impossible to prove theoretically as these are things which we have no idea about. Its more of a philosophical topic than a theory and requires exploration or a visual proof. If we were to put down this theoretically then it would just lead to a contradictory loop as this implies infinite outcomes and infinite universes. In short, it has not been proven theoretically and it will never be proven that way.